# Json key has value or not?

Tags: php, json

i want to know `json` particular key has value or not

please check my below json :

```
[{"highest_education":"B.E ( Automobile Engineering )","occupation":"Job in Private Office","annual_income":""}]
```

in this json i want to check annual_income has value or not in PHP

**i dont want json_decode() and check every value it is not good solution**

Comment: just parse it with json_decode() and check if the parsed array has key that you need.

Comment: my question is particular key has value or not  in my json?  it is not good way to json_decode() and check every key it is to much lengthy and make execution performance speed decrease.

Comment: Why do you think `json_decode()` is not a good solution? It's efficient and much more robust than `strpos()`.

Comment: because i have many json and many keys like this so it is not suitable to every json_decode and check individual key. but now it is ok now i had done. thanks you

Answer (score 0):

First of decode the `json` after decoding you will get array then check particular value with condition

```
 json_decode($myObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

To check annual_income has value or not. You have to first convert your json data into array. like below code.

```
$yourArray = json_encode($yourArray,true);
```

once your json will convert into array than u will check annual_income has value or not.

```
if(!empty($yourArray[0]['annual_income']) && $yourArray[0]['annual_income'] != ''){
  // Not empty
}
```

Comment: my question is particular key has value or not  in my json?  it is not good way to json_decode() and check every key it is to much lengthy and make execution performance speed decrease.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I disagree that `json_decode()` has poor performance; I'll show you the proof below.

To achieve your task, you can use the following codes:

```
$json_string = '[{"highest_education":"B.E ( Automobile Engineering )","occupation":"Job in Private Office","annual_income":""}]';
$json_array = json_decode($json_string, true);
if(isset($json_array['annual_income']) && !empty($json_array['annual_income'])) {
    // value is not null
} else {
    // value is null or empty
}
```

There is no need to iterate through the JSON array at all.

Using PHP 7.1.16, I ran both methods for 1000 times, the performance difference between `strpos()` and `json_decode()` is **not** significant.

```
json_decode() used: 0.001691s
strpos() used: 0.00033s
```

Full test code is here: https://pastebin.com/ZcpjydfK, you can test it on your computer.

On the other side, there is a problem using `strpos()` approach. There is a chance that the JSON string is malformed, or space is added between the colon `:`, then your `strpos()` checking won't work.

Comment: but there is no malformed string.

Comment: As a professional developer, you should always expect the worst. Never assume things are always working as expected.

Answer (score -3):

it is not good way to json_decode() and check every key it is to much lengthy and make execution speed low

i got the right answer

```
$annual_income1='"annual_income":""';
$annual_income2='"annual_income":null';    
if(strpos($json,$annual_income1) !== false || strpos($json,$annual_income2) !== false){ 
echo "annual_income key is empty";
}
```